# Adding google maps with street view to webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, google-maps

Is it possible to add google maps to your website with street view enabled. I've been able to put maps in my web application held in an iframe, but it doesn't have street view?

Any ideas?

Also if it is possible, can we add pins to the map so they can be seen in street view as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visiting the documentation page for [Street View Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService), you can quickly find out samples for:

- [Simple Street View](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple) (street view enabled map, you can embed in your page)
- [Street View Overlays](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays) sample showing how you can have markers visible in street view

That means answer to your questions is **yes**, you can have streetview enabled map in your webpage  and **yes**, you can add pins (markers) that can be seen in streetview.